# Visual Studio 12.0: missing library "msvcmrt"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm trying to use Visual Studio 2015 to compile a VC++ project that, however, targets the Visual Studio 2013 build tools.

I noticed that the Visual Studio 2013 (12.0) tools and libs *seem* to have been installed alongside VS2015, as I see the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\lib directory`, with all the libs. Seems fine.

But... it's not. Two lib files are be missing: `msvcmrt.lib` and `msvcmrtd.lib`, and without these I cannot compile the project.

My question is: how do I acquire these? Do I have to install VS 2013 from scratch? Or is there a more convenient package available to install? Or is my VS2015 installation damaged, and the files should have been there?

Comment: There is no "package", you only get these files from a VS2013 install.

Comment: @HansPassant: correct, installing VS2013 solved the issue. I still don't understand why a partial installation of the libraries is performed... either install a complete, functional version or don't install anything I'd say. Anyway, thanks, rephrase your comment as an answer if you want me to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue and I solved it by simply copying `msvcmrt*.lib` from a machine with vs2013 installed.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\lib
```

There'll be 6 files to copy (x86/arm/x64) * (debug/release)